# How to add another \cc tag in a letter class?

Tags: macros, formatting, letters

I need to create a legal document similar to a letter for a bussiness. I use the stardar class letter for be the best that fit at my needs.

In fact I need to create a formal document but I need to add in the end another field like the one created by the `\cc` tag but I need that this (e.g. `\ccp`) produces a text such as `ccp` or `con copia para`

My document is like this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=155pt,right=115pt,top=72pt,bottom=100pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\address{Distrito Federal, México} 
\date{9 de enero de 2014} 
\signature{\textcolor{white}{Sutano}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{} 
\begin{flushright}
\opening{\textsc{Recibo de pago de anticipo y apartado}
\end{flushright}
} 

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tortor felis, aliquet vitae arcu quis, gravida venenatis mi. Integer lacinia magna id enim viverra egestas. Pellentesque posuere lectus ut turpis malesuada, sed iaculis nunc dapibus. Fusce vel aliquam risus. Vestibulum dignissim libero mattis, ornare tellus in, varius metus. Nunc convallis risus eu varius pretium. Nulla euismod ultrices placerat. Curabitur suscipit nisl consequat adipiscing tristique. Mauris quis neque tortor. Nulla facilisi.

Mauris in dolor et nibh venenatis facilisis feugiat sit amet justo. Pellentesque luctus eleifend ligula, id gravida dui posuere vel. Duis cursus ante tristique dignissim fringilla. Nunc malesuada bibendum est ut ornare. Aliquam condimentum a orci ut rhoncus. In ipsum erat, gravida quis convallis pretium, sagittis vel arcu. Mauris ut luctus mi, sed bibendum dui. Quisque eu augue quis sem placerat laoreet. Sed venenatis tincidunt libero, at congue eros pharetra id. Maecenas non ante nunc. Ut imperdiet consequat justo sodales aliquet.

Integer iaculis porttitor ipsum ac hendrerit. Maecenas consectetur viverra dui, et fringilla leo porttitor non. Fusce sollicitudin nulla vitae lorem ultrices laoreet. Phasellus viverra pulvinar urna ac tempor. Aenean adipiscing tortor turpis, at blandit elit placerat eget. Nulla pharetra est libero, ultricies aliquet nisl scelerisque sed. Vestibulum arcu massa, gravida in dolor ut, egestas ultrices nulla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin semper eget magna a tempus. Fusce sed sodales tellus. Pellentesque egestas dictum lacus, sit amet varius lacus faucibus eget. Quisque ac tellus laoreet mauris elementum laoreet. Pellentesque nec mauris sit amet nulla porttitor consectetur. Praesent tempus elementum purus, eu consectetur sem convallis at.    

\begin{multicols}{2}    
\begin{center}
\underline{\hspace{120pt}}\\
Recibe\\
Fulano
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\underline{\hspace{120pt}}\\
Entrega\\
Sutano
\end{center}
\end{multicols}

\closing{\textcolor{white}{Atentamente}} 
\cc{Sutano} %<--- Will be great can change it for print just cc
%\ccp{Perengano} %<--- This is what I need for print ccp
%\ps{adding a postscript} 
%\encl{} 
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to do it, I hope this won't be hard to do and I hope to be clear with my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy, actually: just use `\cc` under cover.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{letter}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}

\usepackage[left=155pt,right=115pt,top=72pt,bottom=100pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\ccp}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\ccname}{Con copia para}%
  \cc{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\addtolength{\longindentation}{-0.705pt} % fix an overfull box


\address{Distrito Federal, México} 
\date{9 de enero de 2014} 

\signature{\mbox{}} % better than using white print

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{} 

\begin{flushright}
\opening{\textsc{Recibo de pago de anticipo y apartado}}
\end{flushright}

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tortor felis, aliquet vitae 
arcu quis, gravida venenatis mi. Integer lacinia magna id enim viverra egestas. Pellentesque 
posuere lectus ut turpis malesuada, sed iaculis nunc dapibus. Fusce vel aliquam risus. 
Vestibulum dignissim libero mattis, ornare tellus in, varius metus. Nunc convallis risus eu 
varius pretium. Nulla euismod ultrices placerat. Curabitur suscipit nisl consequat 
adipiscing tristique. Mauris quis neque tortor. Nulla facilisi.

Mauris in dolor et nibh venenatis facilisis feugiat sit amet justo. Pellentesque luctus 
eleifend ligula, id gravida dui posuere vel. Duis cursus ante tristique dignissim fringilla. 
Nunc malesuada bibendum est ut ornare. Aliquam condimentum a orci ut rhoncus. In ipsum erat, 
gravida quis convallis pretium, sagittis vel arcu. Mauris ut luctus mi, sed bibendum dui. 
Quisque eu augue quis sem placerat laoreet. Sed venenatis tincidunt libero, at congue eros 
pharetra id. Maecenas non ante nunc. Ut imperdiet consequat justo sodales aliquet.

Integer iaculis porttitor ipsum ac hendrerit. Maecenas consectetur viverra dui, et fringilla 
leo porttitor non. Fusce sollicitudin nulla vitae lorem ultrices laoreet. Phasellus viverra 
pulvinar urna ac tempor. Aenean adipiscing tortor turpis, at blandit elit placerat eget. 
Nulla pharetra est libero, ultricies aliquet nisl scelerisque sed. Vestibulum arcu massa, 
gravida in dolor ut, egestas ultrices nulla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Proin semper eget magna a tempus. Fusce sed sodales tellus. Pellentesque 
egestas dictum lacus, sit amet varius lacus faucibus eget. Quisque ac tellus laoreet mauris 
elementum laoreet. Pellentesque nec mauris sit amet nulla porttitor consectetur. Praesent 
tempus elementum purus, eu consectetur sem convallis at.

\bigskip
\begin{center}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\makebox[120pt]{\hrulefill}\\
Recibe\\
Fulano
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\makebox[120pt]{\hrulefill}\\
Entrega\\
Sutano
\end{tabular}\hfill\mbox{}
\end{center}

\closing{\mbox{}} % better than using white print

\cc{Sutano}
\ccp{Perengano}

%\ps{adding a postscript} 
%\encl{} 

\end{letter} 

\end{document}
```

I've made some adjustments: for printing the signatures you're using a very complicated way, it's easier just using one line and not double column printing. In order to fool `letter` into thinking that something has been typed in `\signature` or `\closing`, it's better to use `\mbox{}` than printing something white.

The string printed with `\cc` is in `\ccname`; what's printed for `\ccp` is in the definition. Just issue

```
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\ccname}{<WHATEVER>}}
```

in the preamble if you want to modify the standard “Copia a”.

[image]